# Option sets for fields?

Tags: entities

In my content type I have a products field (entity reference) which references other content types (product content types). 
What I want to do is each product field has to have a specific option set, and on the node add form the user can choose a product with a specific said option. Example:

Product: Food package A
Options to choose from: Set A, Set B, Set C, etc.

Product: Food package B
Options to choose from: Set A, Set B, Set C, etc.

My Goal:
Choose product: Food package A
Choose option: Set A

I tried editable fields but what happens is the user edits the original product content. BTW I'm not using any commerce module.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand your question. But what is get is you have multiple fields that each one is specific product say, tablet,cellphone,food and every product field has its own specific sets of options.

I recommend you to use [field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) module and set the number of values to `unlimited.` By this module, define the filed collections and specify what sets every product field is free to choose.

Comment: Ok, I also had the idea to use field collection on the products(entity reference) but how can the user choose which OPTION he/she likes?

Comment: I edited the question, hope it will be more understandable.